# Oracle -- finding values with leading or trailing spaces

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find if a certain column requires `TRIM` function on it.

How can I find out if this column in a table has records that have white space either before or after the actual data.

Comment: Do you mean "whitespace" or "space"? The former includes tabs, and the accepted answer won't handle that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check it using the `TRIM` function itself, not the most efficient but accurate:

```
Select *
From TableA
Where MyColumn <> TRIM(MyColumn)
```

Though if you're checking then turning around to trim anyway, you probably want to just do it in the first place, like this:

```
Select TRIM(MyColumn) as TrimmedMyColumn
From TableA
```

Comment: yes this works. but realize this means every query is a full table scan. If doing a lot of queries, consider updating your data to not have spaces.

Comment: @bwawok - +1 - If you're always using it like this it's tremendously better to make it a once time cost and do an update, wasn't sure of the OPs situation in this case.

Comment: @bwawok -- or a fast full index scan.

Answer (score 10):

A quick and dirty way

```
WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(COL1)) <> LENGTH(COL1)
```

Answer (score 2):

So why can't you use the following to find the leading spaces? I've been able to identify the records with leading spaces this way and using '% ' to find the trailing spaces.

```
SELECT mycolumn
FROM my_table
WHERE mycolumn LIKE ' %'
```

I've also used the following to remove both the leading and trailing spaces

```
Update My_table set Mycolumn = TRIM(Mycolumn)
```

which seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [regular expressions](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/application_development/pdf/TWP_Regular_Expressions.pdf) in Oracle.

Example:

```
select * from your_table 
 where regexp_like(your_column, '^[ ]+.*')
    or regexp_like(your_column, '.*[ ]+$')
```

Comment: Your example doesn't need Regex - It would just be `your_column LIKE ' %' OR your_column LIKE '% ' `  I think the Regex woul;d need to be `^[\s]+.*` to match all white space

Answer (score -1):

```
select data1, length(data1)-length(replace(data1,' ','')) from t;
```

Answer (score -1):

Following query will retrieve rows when one of Table fields T$DSCA has trailing spaces at the end:
SELECT * from TABLE_NAME A WHERE RAWTOHEX(SUBSTR(A.T$DSCA, LENGTH(T$DSCA),1)) ='A0' AND TRIM(T$DSCA) is not null;

Comment: Consider describing your solution instead of _"here's the code, goodbye."_

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.