# Trailing spaces plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, trailing

I need to find out the records with trailing spaces. I tried to build a query by using `Length(rtrim)`, however it is not returning the required records.

e.g.

```
abc "
abc       "
abc                                                               "
```

Please assist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle -- finding values with leading or trailing spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223226/oracle-finding-values-with-leading-or-trailing-spaces)

Comment: Here is quite interesting [tip](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_find_leading_trailing_spaces_text_column.htm)

Answer (score 5):

I think you were on the right track. The following example would return the second and third text, but not the first.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 'abc' AS text FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'abc       ' AS text FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'abc                        ' AS text FROM DUAL)
WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(text)) != LENGTH(text);
```

Or for a table `YOURTABLE` with the column `YOURCOLUMN` containing the text with maybe trailing spaces:

```
SELECT * FROM
YOURTABLE
WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(YOURCOLUMN)) != LENGTH(YOURCOLUMN);
```

If you also have `HORIZONTAL TAB`, `LINE FEED`, or `CARRIAGE RETURN` you can use the `TRANSLATE` function to treat these as normal spaces:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 'abc' AS text FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'abc' || CHR(09) AS text FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'abc' || CHR(10) AS text FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'abc' || CHR(13) AS text FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'abc           ' AS text FROM DUAL)
WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(text, CHR(09) || CHR(10) || CHR(13), ' '))) != LENGTH(text);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. But i have thousand of records where trailing are not similar to above examples which i mentioned in my post. Trailing spaces may differ from record to record. There may b single, double, triple and so on. Please assist

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand. What do you mean by single, double, triple? And that trailing spaces may differ from record to record? In my example, one has 0, one has 7 and the other has 24 spaces. The query returns the ones with 7 and 24.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. In my table i have records which has 1,2,3,4,..........100 trailing spaces. and i need to find these type of records.

Comment: Do you want to find all of them at once, or only the ones which have exactly `x` trailing spaces? Let's say `x = 4`. If you want to find all, the above `WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(text)) != LENGTH(text)` should do. If you want to find the ones with exactly `x = 4` trailing spaces, try  `WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(text)) + 4 = LENGTH(text)`

Comment: Hi. Yes i want find all of them at once. I used "LENGTH(RTRIM(PARTY_NAME)) ! = LENGTH(PARTY_NAME)" to find out all of them, however it is returning the records on with single trailing space. Please advice.

Comment: I am running these scripts on TOAD ORACLE

Comment: I updated my answer (see the part about `HORIZONTAL TAB`, `LINE FEED`, and `CARRIAGE RETURN`). Maybe this helps?

Comment: Thanks. I will check this one. and yes i have horizontal tabs in those records. Thanks agian. Will let you know.